JHipster-JDL created primary key autoincrement NO
I used jhipster 8.7.1 to created a Spring Boot app. My database is PostgreSQL.
I found that autoincrement of primary key of jdl-created entity tables is NO.

I wonder how does the Spring framework handle the primary key when doing table insertion.

I did a insertion test, the table ID had a big jump from 10 to 1000+, which seems not very good.

Is there a way to make primary key autoincrement YES for jdl-created table?

